# Error with ngx-clipboard while building the project angular

Tags: angular

ERROR in node_modules/ngx-clipboard/lib/ngx-clipboard.service.d.ts:16:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

16     get isSupported(): boolean;

```
       ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It just happened to me today, installing current last version of ngx-clipboard, version 13.0.0 in Angular 8.

To fix it I downgraded the version installed, to last right version for my Angular 8, the 12.3.0:

```
npm uninstall ngx-clipboard
npm install ngx-clipboard@12.3.0 --save
```

Comment: Thanx Alberto ! yeah it was that , i downgraded the version to 12.0.0 and it works !!

Comment: could you please sort this out at the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. just downgrade ngx-clipboard version with 12.3 and works for me.

```
npm install ngx-clipboard@12.3 --save
```

Answer (score -1):

removing following line from node_modules/ngx-clipboard/lib/ngx-clipboard.service.d.ts
will also get your work done.

`get isSupported(): boolean;`